# Creating different digit multiplication

Tags: python

I am new to Python.

I am trying to create something like this:

```
    A B C

x     D E
__________

F G H I J
```

So some three digit number multiplied a two digit number gives a five digit number. I can create this. However, I need it so that all the digits 0 to 9 are used once in the product and answer.

How could I generate something like this?

Thank you.

Code:

```
from random import randint

x = randint(102, 987)
y = randint(10, 98)

print(x, "*", y, "=", x*y)
```

Comment: What are you trying to make, you did not make it very clear. Also can you show some code that you have worked on?

Comment: Do you want us to give you a specific answer of which numbers would go in which spot?

Comment: Can you post what you have already created?

Comment: My code just generates answers to different 3 digit numbers multiplied by two digit numbers. But I need all the digits 0 to 9 used only once e.g. 317 x 96 = 30432 but this is wrong as 3 is used 3 times and there is no 5 or 8

Comment: @AgentLu That might help

Comment: @Bob can you show us your code so far? It will be easier to help you then

Comment: @Bob Make a list of all the numbers from 0 to 9. Then iterate through all the permutations.

Comment: `itertools.permutations()` should be helpful.

Comment: I think it would take too long to randomly pick numbers and check to see if it works, you would need a strategy so some kind of formula.

Comment: See edited post

Comment: To start it cannot be 999, 100 or 99 beacsue those all have 2 of the same digit. It should be between 102 and 987, and between 10 and 98

Comment: Is there not a way where you can generate them all but the code would pick out the ones I need?

Comment: @Bob: "generate them all" is a REALLY bad idea, given how many there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking advantage of the fact that, once you've picked A-E, F-J are all forced:

```
import itertools

# Find all the ways to assign A-E different digits
for a,b,c,d,e in itertools.product([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], repeat=5):
    used = set([a,b,c,d,e])
    prod = temp = ((a*10+b)*10+c) * (d*10+e)

    # Now add all of the digits in prod to used
    for i in range(5):
        n = temp % 10
        used.add(n)
        temp = int(temp / 10)

    # If all 10 digits used, we have a winner
    if len(used)==10:
        print("%d%d%d x %d%d = %05d" % (a,b,c,d,e,prod))
```

Comment: Are these all possibilities or are there more?

Comment: I ran the code. it said: 356 x 97 = 18042 which is not right?

Comment: It's close to what I want. But obviously with the correct answers.

Comment: Computation of `prod` has been fixed.

Comment: I found the error.((a+10+b)*10+c) should be ((a*10+b)*10+c)

Comment: @ScottHunter could you explain the math behind this in your post. Thanks :)

Comment: The math is all basic arithmetic; what part do you need help with?